# Efficient solver for solving given MINLP problem. (Preferably open source)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to solve an IP optimization problem using DoCPLEX. Here (x_p, y_p) are co-ordinates of points, R is a positive constant and M is a very large positive number.

```
DECISION VARIABLES:
x_c[j], y_c[j]: Continuous variables
g[i,j]: Binary variables
z[j]: Binary variables

OBJECTIVE FUNCTION:
sum(z[j]) for all j

One set of CONSTRAINTS:
R - ((x_p[i]-x_c[j])**2 + (y_p[i] - y_c[j])**2)**0.5 <= M*g[i,j] for all i and j
```

I tried the following:

1. For g[i,j]=0, x_p=0 and y_p=0, we have following equation:

> x_c^2 + y_c^2 >= R^2, which is non convex

2. Tried solving the above problem using docplex.mp.model and got the following error:

> Error: Model has non-convex quadratic constraint, name='C1_00'

3. Tried solving the above problem using docplex.cp.model, assuming all decision variables can take only integer values

> Problem is solvable, but even smaller sized problem involving ~210 binary variable was solved in 45 hours.

Suggest a solver that can solve above MINLP problems (Objective value is discrete and one set of constraints is non-linear) relatively faster. As I need to solver larger problem instances that may involve 10,000+ binary variables within reasonable computation time. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Gurobi can do non-convex MIQCPs. (Just reformulate the **0.5)

Comment: I have checked, it is free (for academic users). What do you mean by formulating this part: **0.5? What type of formulation is to be done for root part?

Comment: Gurobi can do linear and quadratic terms. A square root is not supported. But that is not a real restriction.

Comment: I tried the following transformation:

d = {(i,j): (x_p[i]-x_c[j]) * (x_[i]-x_[j]) + (y_p[i]-y_c[j]) * (y_p[i]-y_c[j]) for i in P for j in C};

constraints = {(i,j) : opt_model.addConstr(
        (R - M * gamma[i,j]) * (R - M * gamma[i,j]) <= d[i,j],
        name="C1_{0}{1}".format(i,j))
    for i in P for j in C};

But it is not giving the correct answer. Am I doing the transformation incorrectly ?

Comment: If you can show that `y=x**0.5 <=> y**2=x, y>=0` does not hold, that would be quite something.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tried including such option but I was unable to do so. Finally, on changing the formulation, it is working fine now.